# Getting started with Openshift and RHEL 6

Tags: rubygems, openshift, rhel6

The [OpenShift Getting Started](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/getting_started) page says to run

```
sudo rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-x86_64-server-optional-6
```

in order to install rubygems in RHEL 6. But when I run that command, I get the output

```
An error has occurred:
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
See /var/log/up2date for more information
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command instead:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
```

See http://web.archive.org/web/20120707214814/http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/entitlements-and-yum.html for more details.

Comment: I've run this command, yet *rubygems* is still not available. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Simply try : yum install rubygems if you goal is to just install rubygems and then rhc

That should work :)